# Use first word of every line as a variable

Tags: powershell, text, count

I have a file with 2 lines and want to set the first word of ever line as a variable. After searching I have the following script:

```
$contents = @(Get-Content C:\testfile.txt)

  foreach($line in $contents) {
  $s = $line -split ' '
  $var1 = $s[0]
  $var2 = $s[1]
  }

Write-Host "$var1"
Write-Host "$var2"
```

The thing is that `$s[1]` is the second word of the first line. How can I get `$var2` to be the first word of the second line and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to tell us what you achieve, this looks a little awkward to me. However, you can only set **one** of your variable with each iteration.

I would use the `-Begin` block of the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet to *initialize* a counter and increase that within the loop:

```
Get-Content 'C:\testfile.txt' | ForEach-Object -Begin {$i = 1} -Process {
    Set-Variable "var${i}" ($_ -split ' ')[0]
    $i++
}
```

---

If you need a less dynamic approach (if there are realy only two lines) you can use this:

```
$content = Get-Content 'C:\testfile.txt'
$var1 = ($content[0] -split ' ')[0]
$var2 = ($content[1] -split ' ')[0]
```

Comment: I have 3 files: two files containing some info and the 3rd containing the number of lines the two files should contain.
I want to check the number of lines of each file to the number in the control file. the number is the first word of each line in the control file. hope this explains it.

Comment: Ok, that make sense. But I wouldn't store these values into variables like `$var1`, `$var2` ... If you start another question where you describe your problem, what you have done and provide sample values including the desired output, we can show you how to do it.

Comment: The less dynamic approached did it. I did not know I could specify the row on which to search. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different approach and wrote the first word to a separate array ($firstword) and then looped through that array for print out.  This should work universally to any text file.

```
$contents = @(Get-Content C:\testfile.txt)
$firstword = @()
  foreach($line in $contents) {
  $firstword += ($line -split ' ')[0]
  }
foreach($word in $firstword){
    Write-Host $word
    }
```